# Get a list of all managed VMs of an ESX through command-line?

Tags: vmware-esx, scripting

Given the IP for an ESX machine I need to be able to retrieve a list of all of it's registered VMs.

I did some scouring around the web and I saw a few vaguely related issues. Solutions ranged from the VMWare API, to batch scripts, etc.

Is retrieving this information from the command line possible out of the box? If not, what kind of steps would I be looking at?

Let me know if I can provide any additional information.

EDIT: Windows command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vmware-cmd -H <vc_server> -U <login_user> -P <login_password> --vihost <esx_host> -l
```

Page 91 of the [VCLI command guide](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r41/vsp4_41_vcli_inst_script.pdf), which was a single google search away by the way

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for finding that for me when I wasn't able to. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need RCLI installed for that on the workstation where you want to do it.

Comment: Guess I'll look into getting this installed. :)